# Brother DCP-J315W printer

Tags: brother

I use Brother DCP-J315W printer and I installed Ubuntu 14. I can not find the driver.

I tried to set up driver via terminal but nothing come up then I try via synaptic with brother driver in the search.

I use driver DCP 350 series instead, If I print , I can see that printer try to retrieve data but nothing is printing.

Comment: Also check that you have ia32-libs or lib32stdc++ installed. It is recommended by Brother.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? Feedback always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The DCP-J315W driver is not available in Ubuntu 14.04 either for direct USB connection or Wireless.
It is because Brother does not make a ddp file available to Lx users for that printer.
On this [page](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html), you will find that printer DCP-315CN is supported. it might differ slightly in terms of functions and features. Just try it.
The driver to be used for it is the [MFC-210C driver](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-210C). I recommend you try to install either the LPR driver ([detailed help found here](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on)) or the cupswrapper driver ([detailed help found here](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpj315w_eu_as&redirect=on)) for deb distros.
Good luck.